# Configuring and limiting output of PI controller

Tags: c

I have implemented simple PI controller, code is as follows:

```
 PI_controller() {

    // handling input value and errors
    previous_error = current_error;
    current_error = 0 - input_value;

    // PI regulation
    P  = current_error //P is proportional value
    I += previous_error;  //I is integral value
    output = Kp*P + Ki*I;  //Kp and Ki are coeficients

 }
```

Input value is always between -π and +π. 
Output value must be between -4000 and +4000.

My question is - how to configure and (most importantly) limit the PI controller properly.

Comment: Please explain the, how to configure part of your question?  Like how to pick the Kp and Ki for your controller?  By limit the PI, do you mean some kind of anti-windup algorithm?

Comment: I mean - how to force the controller not to give lower number than -4000 and greater number than +4000 on the output, providing that input is in range between -3.14 and +3.14. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure your `Kp` and `Ki` you really should analyze the frequency response of your system and design your PI to give the desired response.  To simply limit the output decide if you need to freeze the integrator, or just limit the immediate output.  I'd recommend freezing the integrator.

```
I_tmp = previous_error + I;
output_tmp = Kp*P + Ki*I_tmp;
if( output_tmp < -4000 )
{
  output = -4000;
}
else if( output_tmp > 4000 )
{
  output = 4000;
}
else
{
  I = I_tmp;
  output = output_tmp;
}
```

That's not a super elegant, vetted algorithm, but it gives you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Too much to comment but not a definitive answer. What is "a simple PI controller"? And "how long is a piece of string"? I don't see why you (effectively) code

```
P = (current_error = 0 - input_value);
```

which simply negates the error of -π to π. You then aggregate the error with

```
I += previous_error;
```

but haven't stated the cumulative error bounds, and then calculate

```
output = Kp*P + Ki*I;
```

which must be `-4000 <= output <= 4000`. So you are looking for values of `Kp` and `Ki` that keep you within bounds, or perhaps don't keep you within bounds except in *average* conditions.

**I suggest an empirical solution**. Try a series of runs, filing the results, stepping the values of `Kp` and `Ki` by 5 steps each, first from extreme neg to pos values. Limit the output as you stated, counting the number of results that break the limit.

Next, halve the range of one of `Kp` and `Ki` and make a further informed choice as to which one to limit. And so on. "Divide and conquer".

As to your requirement "how to limit the PI controller properly", are you sure that 4000 is the limit and not 4096 or even 4095?

```
if (output < -4000) output = -4000;
if (output >  4000) output =  4000;
```

Comment: The input, which is in range from -π to π, is effectively phase shift of an input signal. I want to keep the signal at (constant) phase shift of 0 degrees by altering signal frequency. So, if I calculate negative phase shift, I must increase frequency or decrease it if I find out that the phase shift is positive. So I need the output to be in range between -4000 and +4000.

Comment: I understand, but I don't understand statement "which simply negates the error of -π to π."

Comment: @jurij `0 - input_value` negates the input value ... to what effect?

Comment: @WeatherVane Like I said - if the phase shift is positive, I need to decrease frequency, hence I need negative number on the output. Likewise, if the phase shift is negative, I need positive number on the output in order to increase frequency.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking about anti windup for your integrator.

There are more clever ways to to it, but a simple

```
if ( abs (I) < x)
{
    I += previous_error;
}
```

will prevent windup of the integrator.

Then you need to figure out x, Kp and Ki so that `abs(x*Ki) + abs(3.14*Kp) < 4000`

[edit] Off cause as macduff states, you first need to analyse your system and choose the korrect Ki and Kp, x is the only really free variable in the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

```
output =(Kp*(current_err - prev_err))+(Ki*samplingtime*current_err)+output;

if(output>4000)
{
output = 4000;
}
else if(output<-4000)
{
  output = -4000;
}
prev_err = current_err;
```